# Delete rows if date-time is before yesterday

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm quite new to google app scripts, and even javascript.

I have a spreadsheet which logs tweets from twitter.

Col A = Date/Time, Col B = User ID, Col C = Username, Col D = Tweet.

ROW 1 and 2 are headers, tweets start on row 3.

Im trying to delete all rows with date before yesterday (and after yesterday, once I get this to work).

Using the following code:

```
function deleteBeforeDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tweetz");

  var DeleteBefore = new Date();
  DeleteBefore.setHours(00,00,00,00);
  DeleteBefore.setDate(DeleteBefore.getDate() - 1);

  var data = sheet.getRange(3,1,s.getLastRow(),4).getValues();
  var m=0;
  for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
  {
    if (data[i][0] < DeleteBefore)
    {
      sheet.deleteRow(i+2-m); 
      m++;
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason it deletes everything before around 5:20AM rather than midnight. I Can't get my head around it.

Any help with this would be VERY much appreciated.

THANKS!!!

Comment: Sounds like a timezone issue, have you looked into what your time zone is against the server you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by adding some time to account for 6hrs time zone difference.

WORKING CODE FOR ANYONE IN THE FUTURE:

```
function DeletePreviousDates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tweetz");

  var TodaysDate = new Date();
  var TodaysDate2 = TodaysDate;
  TodaysDate2.setHours(00, 00, 00, 001)
 
  var DeleteBefore = new Date(TodaysDate2.getTime() - (29 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (10)); //Hours, Mins, Secs, Milisecs (10ms after midnight, gmt-6)
    
  var data = sheet.getRange(3,1,sheet.getLastRow(),4).getValues();
  var m=0;
  for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
  {
    if (data[i][0] <= DeleteBefore)
    {
      sheet.deleteRow(i+3-m); 
      m++;
    }
  }
}
```

subtracting (29 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (10));

this is time in ms

Replace 29 with 24 for one day (29 here is due to time zone difference)

+10 is 10ms before midnight.

Comment: Note that `TodaysDate2 = TodaysDate` simply creates a second reference to the same Date object, so any changes to *TodaysDate2* will be reflected in *TodaysDate*. Also, to do the timezone offset consider `TodaysDate.setMintues(TodaysDate.getMinutes() - TodaysDate.getTimezoneOffset())`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function deleteBeforeDate() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const dt = new Date();
  const DeleteBefore = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() - 1).valueOf();
  const data = sh.getRange(3, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 2, 4).getValues();//start row 3
  let m = 0;
  data.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (new Date(r[0]).valueOf() < DeleteBefore) {
      sh.deleteRow(i + 3 - m++);
    }
  });
}
```

Check the timezones for your spreadsheet and your script they could be different.

Comment: A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it. `new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() - 1).valueOf()` is effectively what the OP is doing by setting the hours to zero and subtracting a day, so unlikely to fix the issue.

Comment: That's not the only change.